# Notepad ++ Replace function

Tags: replace, notepad++

How do I replace in Notepad ++ (plus plus) `#******`   with `#FFFFFF`?

Basically if my code contains `#000000` `#0F0F0F` `#5tfd5g` and so on, I want every one replaced with #FFFFFF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on Regular Expression mode in the Find/Replace dialog.

```
Find what: #[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}

Replace with: #FFFFFF
```

NOTE: This will only find valid hexadecimal values, not the ill-formed `#5tfd5g`.

Comment: Good answer. The question does not say how `#1234567` and similar should be treated? Should it become `#FFFFFF7` or `#FFFFFF`? It may be worth adding a `\b` at the end of the find what text, making it `#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}\b`. Depending on *exactly* what is wanted, the find what text might be changed to `#[A-Fa-f0-9]+\b`, `#[A-Fa-f0-9]+`, `#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6,}\b` or `#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6,}`

Comment: Ahh, you bring up some good points! I think `#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}\b` might be what OP is looking for: a legal hex color spec. Although, `#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}\b` is also legal. That's the shortened version where `#333` is interpreted as `#333333` and could be replaced as either `#FFF` or `#FFFFFF`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "regular expression" find/replace in NP++:

the `.` character says "anything", so `#......` is `#` followed by any 6 chars.  You can use other regex tricks to get more specific if required.

[image: np++ screenshot w/ regex]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions inside notepad++

In the `Replace` screen, in the left-bottom, you'll be able to change the radio-button to `Regular Expression`

In the `find` option, put `#.{6}`

and in the `replace`, put `#FFFFFF`

Answer (score 0):

Using [regular expresison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) replace. 
search for `#.{6}` replace with #FFFFFF